# Word cannot be opened in Yosemite

Tags: macos, ms-office

I have updated to Yosemite on my MacBook Pro, and suddenly i cannot open Word.

It gives this info:

```
Process:               Microsoft Word [594]
Path:                  /Users/USER/Desktop/Microsoft Word.app/Contents/MacOS/Microsoft Word
Identifier:            com.microsoft.Word
Version:               ???
Build Info:            Unknown-141106~0
Code Type:             X86 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Microsoft Word [594]
User ID:               502

Date/Time:             2015-04-06 17:03:11.663 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.2 (14C1514)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        5E349E81-3EE5-D375-6DA9-20CEBE23AAF4


Time Awake Since Boot: 1500 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: @rpath/mbukernel.framework/Versions/14/mbukernel
  Referenced from: /Users/USER/Desktop/Microsoft Word.app/Contents/MacOS/Microsoft Word
  Reason: image not found

Binary Images:
0x8fe5c000 - 0x8fe8fe03  dyld (353.2.1) <06B1254D-9BB9-327C-BA15-8F18FFF97586> /usr/lib/dyld

Model: MacBookPro7,1, BootROM MBP71.0039.B0E, 2 processors, Intel Core 2 Duo, 2.4 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.62f7
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 320M, NVIDIA GeForce 320M, PCI, 256 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x802C, 0x384A53463235363634485A2D314731443120
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x802C, 0x384A53463235363634485A2D314731443120
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x8D), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.24)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.2f6 15235, 3 services, 19 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: AirPort, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: TOSHIBA MK2555GSXF, 250,06 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-898
USB Device: Built-in iSight
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
USB Device: USB Receiver
USB Device: BRCM2046 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: IR Receiver
Thunderbolt Bus:
```

I can for some reason open Powerpoint... any ideas?

Comment: What version of Word are you talking about?  It's vital to always tell that when asking regarding a problem with this app.

Comment: You may want to try the suggestions in the following MSFT Questions post: [link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2008-macword/why-can-i-suddenly-not-open-any-word-files-on-my/e9d150db-171e-4dfc-a456-b9df1ca7b2f6)

Comment: As a test, see whether you can open the word doc files with this program.
 
LibreOffice   ...                                                                                                                 And if you are using Office 2011 , check whether you have upgraded to the latest version ?

Answer (score 1):

From what you posted up it looks like you have the program installed on your desktop, is that correct? Is Powerpoint located in the same place as Word? This could be causing some issues as Yosemite would have reset some of the permission settings on your desktop during the upgrade.